# Zend DB fetchAll(): where as array

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

I'm confused as to why Zend_DB doesn't accept an array of `WHERE` clauses - or am I incorrect? I have made the following work around:

```
$all = new ORM_Model_DbTable_Asset();
$wheres = array('id > 0', 'enabled' => 1);
$all = $all->fetchAll(implode(' AND ', $wheres))->toArray();
```

for what I hoped would be:

```
$all = new ORM_Model_DbTable_Asset();
$wheres = array('id > 0', 'enabled' => 1);
$all = $all->fetchAll($wheres)->toArray();
```

Slightly disappointing, am I missing something?

Comment: I'd avoid overwriting your `$all` DB Table object with the results array

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [`Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php)

```
/**
 * Fetches all rows.
 *
 * Honors the Zend_Db_Adapter fetch mode.
 *
 * @param string|array|Zend_Db_Table_Select $where  OPTIONAL An SQL WHERE clause or Zend_Db_Table_Select object.
 * @param string|array                      $order  OPTIONAL An SQL ORDER clause.
 * @param int                               $count  OPTIONAL An SQL LIMIT count.
 * @param int                               $offset OPTIONAL An SQL LIMIT offset.
 * @return Zend_Db_Table_Rowset_Abstract The row results per the Zend_Db_Adapter fetch mode.
 */
public function fetchAll($where = null, $order = null, $count = null, $offset = null)
```

So you are incorrect, `fetchAll()` does accept an array of where clauses.

Your array should look like this (based on the definition in [`Zend_Db_Select`](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Db/Select.php))

```
$where = array(
    'id > 0',
    'enabled = ?' => 1
);
```

Comment: in order to use this notation wouldn't $where have to be a select() object? $where = $this->select(); $where->where(array('id > 0', 'enabled =?', 1)); or something similar?

Comment: @RockyFord That's what happens internally when the `$where` (first) argument of `fetchAll()` is an array

Answer (score 1):

First we will look at your original code:

```
$wheres = array('id > 0', 'enabled' => 1);
```

**Remember** that `=>` is an assignment operator.  In your array above you start out with string automatically assigned to key `0`.  The next element is the number `1` assigned to the key `'enabled'`.  The solution proposed in answer 1 assigns the number `1` to key `'enabled = ?'`.

Try this:

```
$all = new ORM_Model_DbTable_Asset();
$where = array();
$where[] = 'id > 0';
$where[] = $all->quote_into('enabled >= ?', 1, 'INTEGER');  // 1 could be a variable
$result = $all->fetchAll($where);
```